# Specify Perl location for makeglossaries

Tags: glossaries, texniccenter, perl

I am using the `glossaries` package to typeset some glossaries, on a MikTeX+TexnicCenter  (Windows) setup.

There are administrative restrictions on the machine which means that I cannot install Perl, which is required in order to run the `makeglossaries` script.

I have downloaded the portable version of Strawberry Perl. But, I am not able to specify the `bin` directory of portable Perl and so `makeglossaries` script is not able to find the Perl interpreter.

Is there any way I can add the location of the Perl to `makeglossaries`?

Thanks.

Comment: I think this question is of topic. Perl+installation+path may be asked here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/perl

Comment: @MarcoDaniel Thanks. I think this is specific to TexnicCenter, since this requires adding the path when TexnicCenter is calling all the required scripts. However, please feel free to close this question, as I have figured out a way to do this.

Comment: The aim isn't the closing ;-). I think you will find more perl experts there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a solution that I have been able to figure out. I make an external batch file (`callmakeglossaries.bat`) that adds the path to the Perl executable, and then calls `makeglossaries`. I add this batch file as a postprocessor in the defined output profile, with the argument `%tm`.

```
REM batch file to run "makeglossaries" after adding path to portable Perl 
REM add the perl location to the path
path = %PATH%;F:\programming\perl\portableStrawberryPerl\perl\bin
"C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\makeglossaries.exe" %1
```

Then I call that output profile from within TexnicCenter a few times. I hope this is of help to someone else too.

**TeXstudio version:**
Follow the same procedure, but add in TeXstudio under Options/TeXstudio configurations/commands/Makeglossaries
`"D:\Users\<...>\callmakeglossaries.bat" %`

Comment: This will work. But why don't you simply add the path to your user PATH environment variable?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer If you don't have admin privileges on a Windows machine, you can't change environment variables.

Comment: You can change the variables of the user.