# Link Portable Perl to makeglossaries

Tags: texmaker, paths, perl

I am using MiKTeX with Texmaker on Windows, and I tried to run the command makeglossaries on Texmaker (which I edited in User Commands) but the Perl interpreter was not found.

Due to very restrictive use on my computer, I can't install Perl, so I downloaded the portable version of Strawberry Perl, to make makeglossaries work. I am not admin, and I can't change path variables on my computer.

A similar question was asked on 
[Specify Perl location for makeglossaries](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/101753/specify-perl-location-for-makeglossaries), but with TexnicCenter instead of Texmaker. The given solution is a batch file as a postprocessor in the defined output profile (which I don't really understand and seems very specific to TexnicCenter).

Could a similar solution be implemented for Texmaker ?

Thanks in advance for your answers.